# Derivative of fiber bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles

Let $\pi:M\rightarrow N$ be a smooth fiber bundle of almost complex manifolds with fiber $F$. Does the map $\bar \partial \pi :T^{0,1}M\rightarrow T^{0,1}N$ make sense? Is it a vector bundle? What is the fiber?